# OSX .NET Messenger Service client with support for offline messages and file transfers

Tags: macos, windows-live-messenger, instant-messaging

Some of my friends use MSN Messenger or Windows Live Messenger. Now I am aware of a variety of clients for OSX but I haven't been able to find one with the following abilities:

- accept / receive file transfers
- receive and send messages from contacts who are invisible (appear offline)

For example:

On Adium, when an invisible contact messages me, the message is sent successfully but never arrives on my end.

edit: I also tried aMSN unsuccessfully. Also I'm not sure if sending messages to contacts that appear offline is classified as offline messsages?

Comment: If they are classified as offline messages I believe only the native MSN client will work since the offline messages are most likely stored on MSNs closed servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:  Have you tried the official [Microsoft Messenger:mac 7](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/messenger/default.mspx)?
Its description sais it supports file transfers. Don't know about the offline messages though.

Otherwise I don't think what you want exists. aMSN will come closest to what you describe. The problem I think is that Microsoft created their own 'protocol' regarding file transfer and offline messages. I even think the Microsoft servers (which are closed) are used as a middle-man for those things.

I think you will have to resort to other "more open" ways of dealing with those problems.

Possible alternatives:

- file transfers: e-mail, [dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com/)
- offline messages: e-mail

Comment: It seems that since the last update to messenger mac the missing functionality has been added, thanks microsoft to helping me move away from windows.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying out [Digsby](http://www.digsby.com), the functions you mention work fine for me on Windows but I am unable to try it on a Mac since I don't have one.

Comment: Digsby is currently not available for mac. It says 'coming soon' on their website.

Comment: Sorry, just looked at their homepage and couldn't imagine that they'd put up download icons for Mac OS X when it wasn't even available for it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried trilian Astra?  They recently reseased a build for OSX.  It does everything you want and more.

http://www.trillian.im/

A quick blurb on the program...
http://www.trillian.im/learn/